# How to use argsparse to accept no flag and flag arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I want to do something like this

Case1:  script.py --a="a_val" --b="b_val"
Both values are required for case 1

Case2: script.py --verify
Just need the --verify without any value

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `argparse`?  What have you tried?  This is extremely basic.  If you're read the documentation, you should have no difficulty implementing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

```
parser.add_argument('--verify', action='store_true')
```